# Should I Parse JSON Data Before Inserting To MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I am receiving some JSON data from a client to my Node.JS server. I want to insert that json into my MongoDB instance using Mongoose.

I can insert the JSON as-is, and it works great, because it's just text. However, I want to parse it before insertion so that when I extract it later it will be all nice and neat.

So, this works:

```
wordStream.words.push(wordData);
```

And this doesn't:

```
wordStream.words.push(JSON.parse(wordData));
```

1. **So, should I even want to parse the JSON before insertion?**
2. **And if I should parse the JSON, how do I do it without throwing an error? I need to put everything in double quotes "", I believe, before it will parse, but for some reason whenever I make a string with double quotes and parse it, it turns everything all wrong.**

Here is the JSON:

```
      { word: 'bundle',
          definitions:
           [ { definition: 'A group of objects held together by wrapping or tying.',
               partOfSpeech: 'noun' } ],
          urlSource: 'testurl',
          otherSource: '' }
```

And the error when I try to parse

```
/Users/spence450/Documents/development/wordly-dev/wordly-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:409
        throw err;
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Ideas?

Comment: any `\t`,`\n` in your json string. may be?

Comment: According to [JSON.parse docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)  "If the string to parse is not valid JSON, a SyntaxError exception is thrown." And regarding `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` it seems you get it because 'o' char is the first character of [object Object] - object default string representation. Try `console.log(JSON.parse({"t":"3"}));` you'll get the same error. So it seems parsing goes wrong here.

Comment: where do you get that JSON from ? Why isn't it quoted with double quotes (both properties and values) ?

Comment: Okay, I definitely am confused here. Why does console.log(JSON.parse({"t":"3"})) not parse correctly? I could swear using the JSON state machine on json.org that that is correct syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, should I even want to parse the JSON before insertion?

Convert the strings to JSON objects will benefit you later, when you need to make queries in your MongoDB database.

> And if I should parse the JSON, how do I do it without throwing an error? I need to put everything in double quotes "", I believe, before it will parse, but for some reason whenever I make a string with double quotes and parse it, it turns everything all wrong.

You aren't receiving JSON documents. JSON documents must contain the keys quoted.

You can:

- Use a library that recognizes invalid JSON objects (please don't)
- Use [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2875514/883113) (this is a security issue, so don't do it)
- Fix the source of the problem, creating real JSON objects. This isn't difficult, you can see the JSON features [here](http://www.json.org/)