# Convert a stringified array into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an easy way to take a string like the one below into an array without writing some kind of complicated parsing function?

```
const stringArray = '[{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value 2'}, {key1: 'value3', key2: 'value4'}, {key1: 'value5', key2: 'value6'}]';
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
const arr = <stringArray CONVERTED TO ARRAY>;
console.log(arr[1].key1); // should log 'value3'
```

If context helps, I'm writing a utility program in JavaScript that involves grabbing and parsing an array input into a `<textarea>` by the user.

Comment: If that mysterious format would be valid JSON, you could `JSON.parse` it easily

Comment: why not take a [JSON (ECMA-404)](http://json.org/) standard compliant string and parse it instead of some fancy lookalike.

Comment: The inner quotes should be double quotes though. The string isn't even valid syntax as-is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse this invalid JSON string in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875318/how-do-i-parse-this-invalid-json-string-in-jquery)